# Get attribute of each element - jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

why `console.log ( $("img").attr("title") );` gets only first title atribute from this?

```
<img src="" title="im the image" />
<img src="" title="im ass well the image" />
```

How can I console log title of each image?

Comment: That's how most jQuery getter methods work. Now what would be your expected result? Getting an array of elements value or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only matching the first element, rather than all `img` tags in the DOM.  To do this you can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$("img").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Full example:

```js
$("img").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" title="im the image" />
<img src="" title="im ass well the image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want an array of the title attributes:

```js
var titles = $("img").map(function() {
   return this.title;
}).get();

   console.log(titles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" title="im the image" />
<img src="" title="im ass well the image" />
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```js
var titles = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('img') ).map(function(img){
  return img.title;
});

   console.log(titles);
```

```html
<img src="" title="im the image" />
<img src="" title="im ass well the image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**the following code can also be used**

```
$('img').each(function (index, value) { console.log($(value).attr("title")); });
```

**Or**

```
$('img').each(function (index, value) { console.log($(this).attr("title")); });
```